# How do I pass and render an object to an extended child template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

So what I'm trying to do is create a view for a child template, so that I can pass in model objects and parameters, and render it accordingly. But is this possible..because two views can't be called once? And two urls (one for child and one for parent template) can't be called at once either. I don't understand how it works or maybe I'm just not looking at it right. Does anyone have any idea?

**urls.py**

```
BV = BoxesView.as_view()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', poll, name='poll'), #child template
    url(r'^$', BV, name='news'), #parent template
]
```

**view.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')
        return queryset_list


def poll(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=1)
    return render(request, 'polls.html', {'question': question})
```

**polls.html**

```
{% extends 'parent.html' %}

{% block polls %}

<p>question goes here</p> #this shows up
{{ question.question_text }} #this doesn't show up


{% endblock %}
```

**parent.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

        {% for post in post_list %}

            {% block polls %}

            {% endblock %}

        {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=70)

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

Answer (score 0):

**urls.py**

If the url to your child template is:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', poll, name='poll'), #child template
```

The view to handle request matching the above url will be handled by the `poll` view as mentioned in `url` 3 arguments are passed to it - the synopsis is:

`url(<regex to match url parameters>, <view to handle the request>, <name of the url>)`:

---

**views.py**

```
def poll(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=1)
    return render(request, 'polls.html', {'question': question})
```

Synopsis for the `view'`s `return` statement:

```
return render(request, <template name to render>, <the context dictionary for passing anything object/python var to the template>)
```

as `'poll.html'` is your child template, it's all set fine for you.

About passing the object to `child.html` - you're already passing the `Question` object here `{'question': question}`,

Comment: I made a mistake, it's not called `child.html` it's called `polls.html` so i've edited that now. The view (child and the parent) actually works but the {{ question.question_text }} isn't rendered. Any idea?

Comment: Everything seems to be ok here - Try enclosing it in <p> </p>